# AudioSource.DOWN_LINK not working in android after 6.0 but working below 6.0

Tags: android, voice-recognition, mediarecorder

I'm developing an application like call recorder where my task is to record only the caller's voice. This feature is working on Android 5.0 and below, but not working for Android 6.0.

The code snippet that I'm using:

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
```